# Position vs Time Function for a Falling Object Without Assumption of Constant Acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, planets, free-fall

If you have an asteroid for example and a planet, isolated from all other gravitational influence and initially at rest with respect to each other, how would you find a position vs time function for the asteroid and the planet falling toward each other?

Comment: Can you give us some idea of your level in science? For example, have you done calculus?